# Using signature file in script

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I like using .fsi signature files to control visibility. However, if I have both  `Foo.fsi` and `Foo.fs` files in my solution, and `#load "Foo.fs"` in a script, it doesn't seem like the corresponding signature file gets used. If I do:

```
#load "Foo.fsi"
#load "Foo.fs"
```

... then the desired visibility control happens. Is this the recommended way to achieve this, or is there a better way to do it? In a perfect world, one would like to see the signature file automatically loaded, too.

Comment: Not a final answer, but a better way. From reading `Expert F# 4.0` one can do `#load "Foo.fsi" "Foo.fs" "Foo.fsx"` All of three loads are on one line.

Comment: @GuyCoder so far, your 'better way' is also the best response. Since then I have given it some thought, and realized it can make sense to include or not the .fsi in a script, because one might want to 'test' the raw code at that point. Anyways, if you put in your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to take it as an accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a final answer, but a better way.

From reading [Expert F# 4.0](http://www.worldcat.org/title/expert-f-40/oclc/934083911&referer=brief_results) one can do

```
#load "Foo.fsi" "Foo.fs" "Foo.fsx"
```

All three loads are on one line.

TL;DR

The link to the book is via [WolrdCat](http://www.worldcat.org/) just put in a zip code and it will show you locations near there where the book can be found.